# F10 Key is not caught

Tags: c#, winforms, events, keyboard

I have a Windows.Form and there overriden ProcessCmdKey. However, this works with all of the F-Keys except for <kbd>F10</kbd>. I am trying to search for the reason why ProcessCmdKey is not called when I press <kbd>F10</kbd> on my Form.

Can someone please give me a tip as to how I can find the cause?

Best Regards, Thomas

Comment: Did you turn F-Lock off?

Comment: Try to use KeyDown event instead, it should work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows treats <kbd>F10</kbd> differently. An explanation is given in the "Remarks" section [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280.aspx)

Comment: He's using ProcessCmdKey rather than KeyDown which should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this code with Windows Forms on .NET 4 and I got the message box as expected.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.F10)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("F10 Pressed");
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: When I create a new Form it is also working there. But I have to find out, why F10 isn't working with the existing form.

Answer (score 1):

May be I got your problem, so trying to guess:

Did you set `KeyPreview` property of your WindowsForm to `true` ?

This will enable possiblity to WindowsForm proceed keypress events before they pump to the control that holds the focus on UI in that precise moment.

Let me know if it works, please.

Regards.

Comment: "However, this works with all of the F-Keys except for F10", at this point I, personally don't see any other answer like if you have some aplication on your PC installed that hooks that key: Multi desktop, some media application... Can you try run your app on other PC?

Comment: Just curiosity @t.kehl, was it something related to my last comment ? Cuase, now actually thinking about that, I expirienced somethign like that in VS 2010 too, when I installed some applicaitons that installe hooks, some shotcut keys stop working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to match e.key to system.windows.input.key.F10 and it didn't not work (althougth F1 thru F9 did)

```
Select Case e.Key

Case is = Key.F10
... do some stuff

end select
```

however, I changed it to

```
Select Case e.Key

Case is = 156
... do some stuff

end select
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If running into this issue in a WPF app, [this blog post](http://geekswithblogs.net/Martinez/archive/2012/04/14/f10-not-working-in-wpf.aspx) shows how to capture the F10 key:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.SystemKey == Key.F10)
        {
            YourLogic(e.SystemKey);
        }

        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.F1:
            case Key.F2:
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, and as this is a special key you must add

```
e.Handled = true;
```

it tells the caller that you handled it.

So, your code could look like:

```
switch (e.Key)
...
case Key.System:
    if (e.SystemKey == Key.F10)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        ... processing
    }
```